# Unable to Add Windows Node Pull to Cluster Using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api

I want to add Windows Server Container to Azure kubernetes Cluster.Currenty,using the Azure Rest API to manage the cluster.But It is showing the following error:

```
{
  "code": "AzureCNIOnlyForWindows",
  "message": "Windows agent pools can only be added to AKS clusters using Azure-CNI."
}

{
  "location": "location1",
  "tags": {
    "tier": "production",
    "archv2": ""
  },
  "properties": {
    "kubernetesVersion": "",
    "dnsPrefix": "dnsprefix1",
    "agentPoolProfiles": [
      {
        "name": "nodepool1",
        "count": 3,
        "vmSize": "Standard_DS1_v2",
        "osType": "Linux"
      }
    ],
    "linuxProfile": {
      "adminUsername": "*******",
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "keyData": "keydata"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "loadBalancerSku": "basic"
    },
    "windowsProfile": {
      "adminUsername": "********",
      "adminPassword": "************************"
    },
    "servicePrincipalProfile": {
      "clientId": "clientid",
      "secret": "secret"
    },
    "addonProfiles": {},
    "enableRBAC": true,
    "enablePodSecurityPolicy": true
  }
}

{
  "code": "AzureCNIOnlyForWindows",
  "message": "Windows agent pools can only be added to AKS clusters using Azure-CNI."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question,  I assume that you want to add the Windows node pool to the AKS cluster. And then the error means you do not use the Azure-CNI network type for your AKS cluster. For the Windows node pool, see below:

> In order to run an AKS cluster that supports node pools for Windows
>   Server containers, your cluster needs to use a network policy that
>   uses Azure CNI (advanced) network plugin.

So the solution for you is to create a new AKS cluster with the Azure-CNI network type. And then add the Windows node pool again. Take a look at the steps that [Create AKS cluster for Windows node pool through Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli#create-an-aks-cluster). And in REST API, you need to set the `networkPlugin` in the `properties.networkProfile` with value `azure`. See [NetworkPlugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate#networkplugin).